# Unknown difference between logic of OOP code compared to Procedural

Tags: python, pygame

I have written two versions of the same bouncing ball game. One is OOP based and one is procedural, and I would expect them to do the same thing. Except, the Object Oriented program behaves differently.

I don't know the best way to explain it but the procedural code 'bouncing' keeps the ball bouncing indefinitely and bouncing to the same height each time. But the OOP code 'bouncing' increases the bounce height on each consecutive bounce. Yet I cannot find a difference in the logic between them.

OOP code

```
import pygame, time
        
class Ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, colour, radius):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([radius*2, radius*2])
        self.colour = colour
        self.radius = radius
        pygame.draw.circle(self.image, self.colour, (radius, radius), self.radius)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = 350
        self.rect.y = 350
        self.change_y = 0.5
        self.vel_y = 0
    def update(self):
        self.vel_y += self.change_y
        self.rect.y += self.vel_y
    def bounce(self):
        self.vel_y = self.vel_y * -1
        self.rect.y += self.vel_y 

def play_game():
    all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
    ball_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
    ball = Ball(WHITE, 10)
    ball_list.add(ball)
    all_sprites_list.add(ball)

    done = False
    while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True
        screen.fill(BLACK)
        all_sprites_list.draw(screen)
        for ball in ball_list:
            if ball.rect.y > 690:
                ball.bounce()
            else:
                ball.update()
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)

BLACK = (0,0,0)
WHITE = (255,255,255)
RED = (255,0,0)
BLUE = (0,255,0)
GREEN = (0,0,255)

pygame.init()
screen_width = 700
screen_height = 700
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([screen_width, screen_height])
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

play_game()
pygame.quit()
```

Procedural code

```
import pygame
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
BROWN = (200, 100, 0)
 
pygame.init()
size = (700, 700)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

rect_x = 350
rect_y = 350
rect_changey = 0

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
    screen.fill(BLACK)  
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, WHITE, [rect_x, rect_y], 10)
    if (rect_y > 690):
        rect_changey = rect_changey* -1
        rect_y += rect_changey
    else:
        rect_changey = rect_changey + 0.5
        rect_y += rect_changey
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
 
pygame.quit()
```

Update: The ball.update() function is running 1 more time than the equivalent part of the code in the procedural code. Still dont know why though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rect_x` and `rect_y` can store floating point values. However `rect.x` and `rect.y` cannot just store integral values.

Since [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) is supposed to represent an area on the screen, a `pygame.Rect` object can only store integral data.

> The coordinates for Rect objects are all integers. [...]

The fraction part of the coordinates gets lost when the new position of the object is assigned to the *Rect* object. If this is done every frame, the position error will accumulate over time.

If you want to store object positions with floating point accuracy, you have to store the location of the object in separate variables respectively attributes and to synchronize the `pygame.Rect` object. [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) the coordinates and assign it to the location (e.g. `.topleft`) of the rectangle:

```py
x, y = # floating point coordinates
rect.topleft = round(x), round(y)
```

`Ball` class:

```py
class Ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, colour, radius):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([radius*2, radius*2])
        self.colour = colour
        self.radius = radius
        pygame.draw.circle(self.image, self.colour, (radius, radius), self.radius)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.x = 350
        self.y = 350
        self.rect.x = self.x
        self.rect.y = self.y
        self.change_y = 0.5
        self.vel_y = 0
    def update(self):
        self.vel_y += self.change_y
        self.y += self.vel_y
        self.rect.topleft = round(self.x), round(self.y)
    def bounce(self):
        self.vel_y = self.vel_y * -1
        self.y += self.vel_y 
        self.rect.topleft = round(self.x), round(self.y)
```

Comment: Why does it work for the procedural code then without rounding?

Comment: @J4ns323 Please read my answer. The rounding is  not the problem. `rect_x` and `rect_y` can store floating point values but `rect.x` and `rect.y`  cannot just store integral values.

Comment: Ohhhhh, I understand now, thanks for clarifying